# Image not displaying and getting error protocol not found in Android

Tags: android, image, protocols

Code for which I am getting and  error "protocol not found" to display an image in image view in Android, See the error I am getting.

```
package com.android.guessthecelebrity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ArrayList<String> celebUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> celebNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        int choosenCeleb = 0;
        ImageView imageview;

        public class  downloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                URL url;
                try {

                     url = new URL(urls[0]);

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return myBitMap;

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String result = "";
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {

                    url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    int data = reader.read();
                    while (data != -1) {

                        char current = (char) data;
                        result += current;
                        data = reader.read();

                    }
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();

                String[] splitResult = result.split("<div class=\"listedArticles\">");

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("img src=(.*?)/>");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

                while (m.find()) {
                    celebUrls.add(m.group(1));
                }

                p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
                m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

                while (m.find()) {
                    celebNames.add(m.group(1));
                }

                Random rand = new Random();
                choosenCeleb = rand.nextInt(celebUrls.size());
                downloadImage imageTask = new downloadImage();
                Bitmap celebImage = imageTask.execute(celebUrls.get(choosenCeleb)).get();
                imageview.setImageBitmap(celebImage);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

I am getting this error

2019-04-14 01:01:05.243 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "http://cdn.posh24.se/images/:profile/06843450e961e1302d12b6951558d684d" alt="Kit Harington"
2019-04-14 01:01:05.244 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:590)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.244 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:487)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.244 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:436)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.245 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$downloadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:35)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.245 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$downloadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:27)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.246 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.246 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.246 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.247 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.247 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-04-14 01:01:05.247 15624-15779/com.android.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

and Image is not displaying on the screen, Really appreciate your help. Thanks.Only blank space is appearing rather than image.
and Image is not displaying on the screen, Really appreciate your help. Thanks.Only blank space is appearing rather than image.
and Image is not displaying on the screen, Really appreciate your help. Thanks.Only blank space is appearing rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use picasso to handle any work for image

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(yoir_image_view);
```

[Here](https://square.github.io/picasso/) is the link for the library

Comment: Thank you. Let me to check it